Exactly what year did Newton first write about calculus, 1664, 1665 or 1666?
Exactly what year did Newton first write about calculus?
I find from different sources three years; 1664 citation needed
, 1665 and 1666, but which year is correct?
1665 source
1666 source
1665 source

"By autumn 1665, Newton had worked out a method for replacing the use of infinitesimal increments of space in his calculations with instantaneous changes in the velocity of a moving point by which curved lines were described. Stimulated entirely by his reading, Newton had invented the method of fluxions, or calculus, through the working in his ‘Waste Book’"


Questions are opened by community vote, and generally only because the question has been edited to address the issues raised in comments.  Recommend you identify the sources for the three years.

I think this needs some clarity as to whether "first write about" means writing in his own notes or writing in a published manuscript. The difference between the dates seems to hinge on that distinction.

See Richard Westfall, Newton's Marvelous Years of Discovery and Their Aftermath Myth versus Manuscript (Isis, 1980): "In the beginning of the year 1665 I found the Method of approximating series & the Rule for reducing any dignity of any Binomial into such a series. The same year in May I found the method of Tangents..." By the autumn of 1666 he was able to compose what is known as the October 1666 Tract, in which he applied the fluxional method successfully to problems of tangents (or differentiation), quadratures (or integration), centers of curvature."

According to Wikipedia, Newton's first work about calculus was in 1666. This paper and others are available in The Mathematical Papers of Isaac Newton published by Cambridge Press.
